# Check column value then execute a shell if true otherwise execute a different shell

Tags: shell, conditional-statements

I haven't had much luck with a code to check column 4 values in a text file called Test.txt, and if the values are greater than 0, then execute A.sh, otherwise execute B.sh.

Here's what I have

```
while read mLine; do
  mFld4=$(echo ${mLine} | cut -d'' -f4)
  if [[ "${mFld4}" > "0" ]]; then
  A.sh
  else
  B.sh
  fi
done < Data.txt
```

For now, A.sh only contains one line of code:

```
echo "Column 4 is greater than 0"
```

My file; Test.txt has column 4 values greater than 0 in all 4 rows. This is the output I got:

```
Column 4 is greater than 0
Column 4 is greater than 0
Column 4 is greater than 0
Column 4 is greater than 0
```

The problem is I only need A.sh executed once as long as one or more rows of Test.txt column 4 has a value greater than 0.

In other words the loop should stop the first instance it encounters a column 4 value > 0

A.sh does not need to be executed 4 times. Once is sufficient.

Comment: Why not `while read col1 col2 col3 col4 junk; do if [ "$col4" -gt 0 ]; then A.sh else B.sh fi ...` if your delimiter is `'|'`, then  `while read col1 sep col2 sep col3 sep col4 sep junk ...`

Comment: Thanks but I get an error message : 0.205282: integer expression expected even when I changed -gt 0 to -gt "0"

Comment: I edited original post

Comment: What that tells me is what you get in `col4` isn't an integer value. Print out the values and see what you have, e.g. `printf "col1 : %s\ncol2 : %s\ncol3 : %s\ncol4 : %s\n" "$col1" "$col2" "$col3" "$col4"`

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
while read mLine; do
      mFld4=$(echo ${mLine} | cut -d'' -f4)
      if [[ "${mFld4}" > "0" ]]; then
    break
      A.sh
      else
      B.sh
      fi
    done < Data.txt
```

Comment: `if [[ "${mFld4}" > "0" ]];` is wrong. The `'>'` meta operators is a lexicographical sort within `[[ ... ]]`, NOT a comparison operator. It is only comparison within `(( ... ))` See [man bash](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) under "CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS" (3rd paragraph)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).